# javascript - reference DOM for a variable every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, server-sent-events

The title of the question may seem misleading as I know you should not use variable if you want to reference the DOM every time. However, the scenario is a bit different; I've created an SSE script that works perfectly the first time the page is loaded but since the content of the page is constantly changing it won't always work.

```
var objts = $(".newsItem:first").data("ts");
var objid = $(".newsItem").data("id"); 
var ids = $.makeArray(objid); //variable of IDS
var ts = $.makeArray(objts); //variable of ts

var source=new EventSource("AJAX/get_feed_updates.php?ids=" + ids + "&ts="+ ts +"");

source.onmessage=function(event)
  {
    if (event.data > 0){
        document.title = '(' + event.data + ') ' + originalTitle;

    if (event.data == 1){// no plurals
           $("#refreshFeed").fadeIn('slow').html(event.data + ' more news item.');
     }

     if (event.data > 1){ //plurals
        $("#refreshFeed").fadeIn('slow').html(event.data + ' more news items.');
     }
}
};
```

As you can see the first variable get the data into an array to put into the `EventSource` url. Obviously, this will not continue updating as the page does and neither wil `source`. I tried stringing everything together so instead of `source.onmessage...` it became;

```
new EventSource("..." + $.makeArray($".newsItem")...).onmessage=function(event)
```

But that did not work as the Event Source does not change. I want the DOM to be referenced EVERY single time the SSE source is requested. I know this is not a good way of doing these things but I can't see a way around it in this case.

Comment: What about a setter and a getter instead of a variable?

Comment: @11684 Haven't heard of them but i'll look into. Have any useful links that i may not find in a quick search?

Comment: Getters are just functions that retrieve a value for you (I.e. `getFoo()`) and setters are functions that set a value (`setFoo(newValue)`). In your case, I would make a function called `getIdArray()` instead of a variable. In that function gett these IDs and put them into an array. The Same for the TSs. (The setter (might you need it) should then update the corresponding IDs and TSs. But if you don't need it, don't try it. Updating the DOM from an array will mess up your code with loops, etc.)

Comment: Whoa, wait, I thought you needed the variables `ids` and `ts` updated. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case I would not use `EventSource` since you need to pass it information.

Try using websockets or use some sort of Comet technique.

Comment: That will not work as `source` must be outside the function so it can be referenced by the function.

Comment: Thanks, I do have a polling technique as a backup but this site is all about new technology so I really want to take advantage of new technologies that came with HTML5

Comment: @nbs189 use websockets. EventSource is only for **getting** information. Not for sending information.

Comment: I will have a look into it but I need to send a little information to get a lot if you see what I mean. Thanks for the help anwyay